# If multiple edit buttons is having same HTML coding how will I click the button in Selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm new to Selenium. Below is code:

```
<i _ngcontent-c13="" aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-edit" style="color: green;cursor: pointer;"></i>
```

I have all edit buttons with the same type. How do I click on each of the buttons? Can anyone help me with the XPath?

Comment: Which Selenium binding art? Java/Python/C#? Your code trials and error stack trace (if any)

Comment: java using selenium

Comment: driver.findElement(By.xpath("//i[@class='fa fa-edit']")).click();

Comment: Update all these relevant information within the main question for proper analysis

Comment: any coding example

Comment: Provide HTML sample, parents of this elements should be different.

Comment: <div _ngcontent-c3="" class="edit_delete_icon">
                <i _ngcontent-c3="" aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-edit" style="color: green;cursor: pointer;"></i>
                <i _ngcontent-c3="" aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-trash" style="color: red; cursor: pointer;"></i></div>

Comment: When you add additional information, you need to edit it into the question so future readers don't have to read all the comments to find all the relevant info to answer the question.

Comment: My guess is that you will have to build an XPath that references the label for the specific Edit button you want to click. Is it in a table format or ??? Add more of the relevant HTML or preferably add a link to the page.

Comment: It would also be best if you edit your original question to include these updates rather than posting things in the comments. The more you improve the original question the more likely people will feel like taking the time to answer it.

Answer (score -2):

***EASY***

Right click on element in browser > inspect > right click on the highlighted code > copy > copy xpath. Now we have the xpath so:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("paste_xpath")).some_action();
```

Let me know if this works, there are more other options to discuss + add the code block that contains all the buttons.

***HARD***

First we need to get the xpath, you can build it based on the formula:

```
Xpath=//tagname[@attribute='value']
```

Where:

- // : Select current node.
- Tagname: Tagname of the particular node.
- @:Select attribute. Attribute: Attribute name of the node.
- Value: Value of the attribute.

More details you can find [HERE](https://www.guru99.com/xpath-selenium.html)

Thanks,

Comment: This is not relevant to the question.

Comment: @PrashanthVenkat, please add more information, the code block that contains all the buttons.

Comment: <div _ngcontent-c3="" class="edit_delete_icon"> <i _ngcontent-c3="" aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-edit" style="color: green;cursor: pointer;"></i> <i _ngcontent-c3="" aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-trash" style="color: red; cursor: pointer;"></i></div>

Comment: Can you try using CssSelector, inspect element and copy CssSelector.

driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("paste_css")).click();

Comment: @Infern0 how is not relevant? He is trying to use xpath + he is new using selenium. I explained the concept and what should do. Before marking the answer as useful check the question

Comment: @NeaguV he is trying to click specific element, but when the element is common (same as others) he need to perform other strategy, NOT just to click random array of elements.